# How to step debug a PHP HTTP request (GET) with a basic auth in PhpStorm?

Tags: php, debugging, xdebug

I want to run debugger in http request (method type: GET) and it also contains basic auth. But how should I pass basic auth with the request, since PhpStorm is only showing query string for GET method. Please help!

Comment: Please clarify your question. The basic auth works in general: https://i.imgur.com/ZUTVIGi.png

Comment: @LazyOne Actually what I was trying to do is to debug and profile the code when any request hits the PHP server. I was trying PHPStorm for the first time. But after understanding I found out that I was doing the setup incorrectly so instead of tracing a HTTP req I have to start a PHP server inside the PHPStorm .and this alone will do. But surely thanks for the quick reply

Comment: OK. Anyway, check these links if you have not seen them yet: 1) https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/debugging-with-phpstorm-ultimate-guide.html 2)  https://www.jetbrains.com/phpstorm/documentation/debugging/